# ReactNative - AsyncStorage clear while developing app

Tags: javascript, react-native

Is there any way (for example from developer menu in react app) to clear AsyncStorage while developing or debugging app?

It would be really helpfull. Now I have to reinstall debug apk or call clear() upon start, which is not always wanted behaviour upon every start.

Or is there any plugin which allow this in more accessible way?

Comment: the pepperoni-app-kit has a simple example of `AsyncStorage`-clearing / custom developer menu: https://github.com/futurice/pepperoni-app-kit/blob/master/src/utils/snapshot.js and https://github.com/futurice/pepperoni-app-kit/blob/master/src/components/DeveloperMenu.ios.js